# Is it possible to Multiply elements in the array if the elements value is greater than 10?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, int, multiplication

```
public class IntArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number [] = {5, 7, 30, 40,};
        int i;
        int product;
        int answer;
        for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(number[i] + " ");
            if (number[i] >= 10)
                product = number[i] * 2;
            answer = product;
            System.out.println(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to multiply my array? What i really want is to have 10 elements but i tried 4 elements for trial and i want these elements to be multiplied by 2 whenever the element is greater than 10...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you facing any issues If you do so ?

Comment: @SURESH ATTA error: variable product might not have been initialized this is my problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Since this is definitely a learning exercise, here are some hints at how to do it:

Your loop assigns the value `number[i] * 2` to `product`, which gets discarded after each iteration. Instead of doing that, use `number[i] *= 2;` <sup>*</sup>, and remove the declaration of the `product` variable.

You can also discard the `answer`, because it is only assigned, and never used after that.

---

<sup>*</sup> That's a shortcut for `number[i] = number[i] * 2;`

Comment: I want to clarify that `number[i] *= 2` is the same as `number[i] = number[i] * 2`

Comment: @dashblinkenlight How about my condition that if the element inside the array is greater than 10 it will be multiplied by 2

Comment: @Joey You have that covered already: the `if` statement should do the trick.

Comment: @dashblinkenlight can i create method so that i can separate them into two methods first method shows the original then second method shows the multiplied result???

Comment: @Joey Absolutely, you can. You can also create a method that shows an array of `int`s, and call it twice - once before you do the multiplication, and once after the multiplication is done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

In addition to dasblinkenlight's hints, here's one more for you.

You'll run into run-time errors depending on how big your numbers are.  The `int` type can only handle numbers so big.  If the number you're multiplying by 2 is more than half of this number, you either (a) won't get the result you want, or (b) the program will come to a screeching halt, because you're also storing the doubled number in an `int`.  Consider how you'd get around this.